# Unable to login using to Kaggle using kagglehub.login() from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, kaggle

I'm trying to login to kaggle to download a ML model but using VS Code I'm not prompted to input my credentials.

I have tried to login using Google Colab using the following code

```
import kagglehub

kagglehub.login()
```

And, as expected, I get the following login screen:

[image: Login Kaggle from Google Colab]

But when I run the same code in VS Code I just get no output from that cell. My guess is that that functionality is *only* available in a Colab Notebook, but I wanted to make sure of that.